# Why i don't seen flash alert message on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I override `SessionsController` I tried to block not real users but after a page refresh, I don't seen the flash alert message.

this code on **session_controller.rb**

```
  #skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user
  #before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    # super do |user|
    #   byebug
    # end
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    if !real_user()
      signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
      flash[:alert] = "Invalid user"
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end
end
```

and this on **new.html.erb**

```
<ul class="mtn">
  <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
   <%- if name == "alert" %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

after redirect **flash[:alert]** is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the flash directly on the redirect call?

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: "You have successfully logged out."
redirect_to root_url, alert: "You're stuck here!"
redirect_to root_url, flash: { referral_code: 1234 }
```

From https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: I tried all combinations and it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a redirect to the login page, that's because if the page redirects to the base address => '/'.

After that, the route redirects automatically to log in - because the user - not signed-in.

So basically flash-object clear after the route finish and in this case, happened two routes.

This code solved it.

```
redirect_to login_path, alert: 'Your alert here.'
```